# Decode AAC from WebRTC stream in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, stream, webrtc, aac

[Mozilla Firefox dose not support AAC audio decode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Audio_codecs) (It relies on OS or External library). Is there any library to decode AAC from WebRTC stream? I am using Kinesis JS SDK.

Comment: Did you try anything (research for a library)? From [Google search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=decode+aac+javascript) the first result **AAC.js** is a decent decoder. I don't use WebRTC so I'm not sure if the AAC data comes with an AAC header (called ADTS) or else if it is removed (not needed since the WebRTC code might set playback details like samplerate, bitrate and channels etc). Also try to get a free **hex editor** to see the (saved) bytes of your incoming AAC data to check if you have an [AAC header](https://www.p23.nl/projects/aac-header/) (usually starts `FF F1`).

Comment: PS: AAC.js expects an ADTS header first then followed by actual AAC compressed audio data. If WebRTC doesn't have it per audio frame then you'll have to create one (write values into an Array). You can Google search how to calculate AAC frame length (based on audio settings like its sample rate etc).  Maybe **ask a new Question** when you can provide details about received AAC to be decoded (received meaning written into some Array as buffer).

Comment: Thanks for comment @VC.One. Sure we do google before asking question! I know about AAC.js which get aac audio(not my case)! While I am working on writing a code to support AAC on WebRTC stream in Mozilla Firefox, I was looking for a quick solution which written by someone already(to save time and not reinventing the wheel)!